# Redirection in join and cat

Tags: bash, redirect, process-substitution

I wonder how redirection is used in this example from this site https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/

Here is the Input

```
$ cat wine.txt
White Reisling Germany
Red Riocha Spain
Red Beaunes France

$ cat reviews.txt
Riocha Meh
Beaunes Great!
Reisling Terrible!
```

Here is the command and the result

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k 2 wine.txt) <(sort reviews.txt)
Beaunes Red France Great!
Reisling White Germany Terrible!
Riocha Red Spain Meh
```

But in this case double use of < doesn't work

```
$ cat file 1
Hello
$ cat file 2
World
```

I expect

```
$ cat <file1 <file2    
Hello World
```

But result is

```
World
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<(cmd)` is a process substitution. It shares a character with -- but is entirely unrelated to -- the `<` used for redirection:

- `<(cmd)` expands to a filename that you can open and read to get the program's output. You can pass as many filenames as you want to a command.
- `< filename` opens a filename as file descriptor 0. Opening a new file on the same file descriptor overwrites and closes the previous one.

Your process substitution example simply passes two separate filenames:

```
$ echo join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k 2 wine.txt) <(sort reviews.txt)
join -1 2 -2 1 /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/6
```

If you similarly pass two filenames to `cat`, you get the same kind of result:

```
$ cat file1 file2
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example needs to be rewritten as this, for it to work as expected:

```
cat <(cat file1) <(cat file2)
```